# Length of an integer is part of its digits

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, number-theory

How many positive integers less than 1,000,000,000 contain their length as part of their digit string?
Example: 123466 has a length of 6 and 6 is one of its digits. Hence this number needs to be counted.

Comment: Do you mean that it's length is one of its digits?  Or would any 150 digit number starting with 150 count as its length being part of its digits?

Comment: If my number has 12 digits does 100120000007 count?

Comment: digit is only 0-9 so 150/ 12 in above example is not valid

Comment: I don’t think this question is worded correctly, then — to me, @BernardoRecamánSantos and postmortes’ conjectures are both valid; and nowhere in the question does it say the length needs to be a single digit. Your question asks “How many integers less than 1,000,000,000 contain their length as part of their digit string?” instead of what you’ve actually asked.

Comment: @El-Guest - thanks for your hint, I corrected the question as suggested by you

Comment: should this question perhaps say "*positive* integers"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> For any $d$ the number of integers of length up to $k$ with no digit $d$ (where $1\leq d\leq9$) is $9^k$ since each of the $k$ digits (padding at left with zeros if need be) is allowed to be one of 9 things. Hence, the number of length exactly $k$ with no digit $d$ (for any particular $d$) is $9^k-9^{k-1}$. This is true in particular when $d=k$, so the number of length-$k$ numbers not containing their length (when $1\leq k\leq9$) is also $9^k-9^{k-1}$, and therefore the number of length-$k$ numbers that *do* contain their length is $(10^k-10^{k-1})-(9^k-9^{k-1})$ which we might prefer to write as $(10^k-9^k)-(10^{k-1}-9^{k-1})$. Summing this for $k$ from 1 to 9 we get $(10^9-9^9)-(10^0-9^0)=10^9-9^9$.

This equals

> 612579511, a figure already found by Glorfindel by looking it up in OEIS, but as can be seen above the calculation is very straightforward.

Comment: Hurray for telescoping series!

Answer (score 10):

The answer is

> 612579511

Reasoning: there are

> - 1 number of length 1 with digit 1
> - 18 numbers of length 2 with digit 2 (12, 22, ... 92, and 20 ... 29, but don't count 22 twice!)
> - 252 of length 3 with digit 3 (90 ending on 3, 81 where the middle digit is 3 but the last one isn't, 81 where the first digit is 3 but the last two aren't)
> - We could enumerate the rest, but that would be tedious. Fortunately, the sequence is in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A088924) ...
> - 4: 3168
> - 5: 37512
> - 6: 427608
> - 7: 4748472
> - 8: 51736248
> - 9: 555626232
> - Summing them gives the final answer.

Comment: your answer is correct, but there is another  clever way to get this result...

Comment: What about a 10-digit number containing the digits `10` in order, etc.?

Comment: only digits from 0 to 9 are allowed.

Comment: There are no 10 digit numbers less than 1,000,000,000.

Answer (score 8):

There is an other way to find the solution.

> Since we are limited to digit $0-9$, we are interested by the numbers
>  between $1$ and $999,999,999$. We now remove the numbers that doesn't
>  satisfy the condition.
>
>  How many 1 digit numbers doesn't have the number $1$ in it? There are
>  $8$ such numbers.
>
>  How many 2 digits numbers doesn't have the number $2$ in it? There are
>  $8\times9$ such numbers.
>
>  How many 3 digits numbers doesn't have the number $3$ in it? There are
>  $8\times9\times9$ such numbers.
>
>  More generaly, how many k digits numbers doesn't have the number $k$
>  in it? There are $8\times9^{k-1}$ such numbers.
>
>  Our answer is
>  $$999,999,999-8-8\times9-8\times9^2-8\times9^3-8\times9^4-8\times9^5-8\times9^6-8\times9^7-8\times9^8=612,579,511$$

Answer (score 4):

Given any positive integer,

> it is always possible to construct another integer with that many digits that includes the original integer itself.

Therefore, there are *at least*

> as many such integers as there are all integers altogether.

There cannot be any more than that, because the resulting integers are, well, integers.

Comment: Note that this answer was written before the question was edited to specify integers _up to 10^9_.

Comment: This one gets an upvote from me as well, because based on the original parameters of the question it is most correct!

Answer (score 3):

If you

> pad the numbers with leading zeroes so that they always have 9 digits

then it becomes easier to count how many there are because you then don't have to split it into cases.

> There are $10^9$ strings of 9 digits. Those that start with one or more zeroes represent numbers with fewer digits.
>
>  There are $9^9$ strings of consisting of the digits $0$ to $8$. Any such string uniquely corresponds to a number not containing its length: If its length is $n$, just increment every digit that is $n$ or greater (the length is not affected by incrementing non-zero digits so this process is reversible).
>
>  Therefore there are $10^9-9^9$ numbers containing its own length as a digit at least once.

Comment: +1 for the first direct method.  Another way: taking all numbers with digits 0-8, i.e. digits 0-9 but excluding digit 9, then replacing the digits matching the length with digit 9, you get all number with digits 0-9 but excluding its own length.